# Celery + Django - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery.backends.amqp'

Tags: django, celery

I have no clue why I am getting this error. My ´requirements.txt´ file includes:

```
amqp==5.1.1
celery==5.2.7
```

I have followed the standard configurations [here](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html): Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: See https://github.com/tanchinhiong/decoupled-celery-example/issues/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of version 5.0, the amqp backend has been removed from Celery core. You can either replace it with a third party package such as https://pypi.org/project/celery-amqp-backend/ or use `rpc://`.

It looks like there is a bug in the original 5.0 release: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/6384

But it is fixed with https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/7805

I'm not sure if this has made it to pypi, though.

After some more research, it looks like this fix is slated for 5.3 to be released in May: https://github.com/celery/celery/milestone/36

Comment: Converting this to 'rpc://' solved my issue